# If a cell is equal to one of the elements of a list then get data from another cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet that gathers data from a Google Form. In this form, we ask the users to choose between the different seating plans.

This is an example of the data gathered in the Response sheet:

```
        column A               
row 1 | Workshop
row 2 | Conference
row 3 | Story time
row 4 | Conference
row 5 | Workshop
```

In column B of the Response sheet, I want the **image of the plan** to appear depending on the data from column `A`. For example, the Workshop seating plan would be "Plan A" and the Conference seating plan would be "Plan B" and so on. I have the name of the plans and the **images of the plans** in another sheet called "Validation".

The sheet Validation is like this:

```
         Column A     Column B           
row 1 | Workshop   |   Plan A
row 2 | Conference |   Plan B
row 3 | Story time |   Plan C
```

Is there a formula that would allow me to accomplish this? Or maybe a script?

EDIT: Here is an example sheet of what I want to accomplish:

**Response** sheet should look like this:[image: Result wanted]

**Validation** sheet should look like this: [image: Validation sheet]

Here is a link of a test sheet (without a working formula): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QM9m0ue0Isgw1m1a3ww470GF_5Pvxd3P5n-pNdJFOKY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome. Please do share a test form and spreadsheet as well as your efforts. Also, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well -. ([Why vote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need a script. Try the next formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A:A,Validation!A:B,2,),""))
```

[image]

Comment: Hello ! Thank you for your answer, unfortunatly when I try it in my sheet it returns an error. Here is an example spreadsheet I made with your formula: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QM9m0ue0Isgw1m1a3ww470GF_5Pvxd3P5n-pNdJFOKY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I also edited my original comment for more clarity and made a test spreadsheet.

Comment: I don't know if it's because my sheet is in French, but the formula worked after I changed the , to ;. Thank you for your answer and the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following (similar to @contributorpw) formula.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A222,Validation!A1:B,2,)," "))
```

The essential difference is using a closed end column for column `A`

[image: vlookup closed end column]

Comment: I don't know if it's because my sheet is in French, but the formula worked after I changed the , to ;. Thank you for your answer and the help!

Comment: So, did you finally use open end columns (`A:A`) and worked??

Comment: Both solutions worked for me!